# How to use data of curl -v?

Tags: shell, curl

I used `curl -v xxx` in shell to get data, like

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 21 Jan 2021 03:20:45 GMT
Content-Type: application/x-gzip
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
cache-control: no-store
upload-time: 1610523530924
...
```

While I used command `res=$(curl -v xxx)`, and then `echo res`, it is empty, and those information printed in the terminal as well.

So how can I get the field `upload-time: 1610523530924`?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I know. The inforamtion of head is in `stderr`, so if you want to print out, it is necessary to redirect it to `stdout`. Use `curl -v xxx > tmp.txt 2>&1`.